# Именованные элементы массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы

[image: Скриншот с наглядным примером о том о чем я хочу узнать]

Недавно наткнулся в консоли на массив, у которого наряду с нумерованными элементами есть именованные свойства как у объекта, при изучении JS, я не сталкивался с подобным, и всегда думал, что массив может иметь только нумерованные поля(на скрине видно что длина массива считается именно только по колличеству нумерованных элементов).

Объясните пожалуйста, что означают выделенные именованные свойства и как можно создать такой массив

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: вы имейте ввиду скрин, кода?

Comment: [Это норма](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzmb4.jpg). Массив в джаваскрипте - это больше чем массив. На самом деле к классическому массиву из FORTRAN / C он не имеет никакого отношения, правильнее его называть map. В качестве ключей могут быть либо числа (причем заметьте, что целых чисел в джаваскрипте тоже нет) или строки.

Comment: Массив - это объект класса Array. И как любой объект он может иметь поля. Как создать? Например так - arr.test = 'test'

Comment: да спасибо! я протестил, правда в интстансе массива появляется свойство, просто я не понимаю как тогда работает в данном случае итерируемость, в основных методах не береться в счет, но по именованным меткам можно как-то проитерироваться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется "Ассоциативные массивы"

Все в js - это примитивы (`boolean`, `null`, `undefined`, `bigint`, `number`, `string`, и `symbol`) и объекты (все остальное). Если мы сделаем typeof на массив, то получим object.

Например, мы можем создать коллекцию `Map`, которая сделаем нам ассоциативный массив.

```js
const arr = new Map([
  ['key1', 'value1'],
  ['key2', 'value2'],
  ['key3', 'value3']
]);

console.log(arr)
```

---

Но исходя из того, что все в js это object, мы можем создать новый стандратный массив и подобно обьекту записать в него свойство

```js
let arr = [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ];

arr["string"] = 'test'
arr.string2 = 'test2'

console.log(arr)
```

Если посмотреть в хроме в консоле данный массив, то мы получим

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, string: 'test', string2: "test2"]
0: 0
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
string: "test"
string2: "test2"
```

Comment: спасибо! по именованным ключам можно как я понял итерироваться? a есть ли практическое применение такого гибрида?

Comment: язык возможностей... :)) Всегда можно найти полезное применение, если есть такая возможность. Но мне не доводилось пользоваться этой возможностью. Может кто другой прокомментирует. )

Answer (score 1):

В Javascript массивы - это объекты класса `Array`. А любому объекту можно установить произвольные свойства

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.field1 = 'ABC';
arr.field2 = 42;
console.log(arr);
```